# Can't run simple bash script

Tags: bash

I try executed some like this

```
#!/bin/bash
${postid=41930}
while ${postid} < 42000;
do
 `node title.js ${postid}`
  ${postid} = ${postid} +1;
done
```

I have this error:

```
: command not found30
run.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$
```

From man sh

```
while *list*;do *list*;done

sh version 3.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places in your script needs to be fixed:

1. As chepner said you can't assign value to an evaluated result like `${postid}`, instead use `postid` directly in the left hand side of your assignment
2. There should be some invisible characters in your script. Try to run `dos2unix myscript.sh` or try hand typing the the following code into an new file

https://gist.github.com/1651190

- sorry i can't format the code correctly, so please check the gist at https://gist.github.com/1651190

Comment: Big thanks for your solutions. I must use vi :set ff=unix . And know all worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Another quick way, using only bash features is:

```
#!/bin/env bash
for postid in {41930..41999} ; do node title.js ${postid} ; done
```

References: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion

Comment: bc-c8-d8-eb-65:googlecache macbookpro$ sh run.sh 
run.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Except if there are hidden characters in you file, I don't know what is wrong. Did you hand-type the code?

Comment: I'm surprised you had to do that in the first place. It should work out of the box if the file was created on your Mac. Or did the file originally come from another editor? Or did you copy a .vimrc from somewhere else? This _could_ explain the problem.
Anyhow, I'm glad you found your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you want

```
for((postid=41930;postid<42000;++postid)) do
 node title.js $postid
done
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for((postid=41930;postid<41940;++postid)) do
 node title.js $postid
done

$ sh run.sh
'un.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'un.sh: line 2: `for((postid=41930;postid<41940;++postid)) do

Comment: @v.tsurka, the question is tagged `bash`, not `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are probably what you want to use. FYI, here's where your errors came from.

```
${postid=41930}
```

To assign 41930 to `posted`, just use `postid=41930`. Note there are no spaces around the equals sign!

```
while ${postid} < 42000;
```

The {} around `postid` are optional; `$postid` works just as well.. You do need to wrap that conditional expansion in a command, as the while loop can't use a bare expression. Something like `while [ $postid < 42000 ];`. Note that in this case, you must have spaces separating the `[` and `]` from the rest of the expression.

```
do
    `node title.js ${postid}`
    ${postid} = ${postid} +1;
```

In order to assign a value to a variable, bash does not allow spaces around the equal sign. With spaces, it interprets this line by expanding `$postid` and treating that as a command to run, with `=` as the first argument. Use `postid=$postid + 1;`. On the left, no dollar sign is needed, as you are not expanding the value of a variable, but assigning to a name. On the right, you need the dollar sign to get the *value* of `posted`.

```
done
```